# A question about do calculus

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, causality, dag, causal-diagram

Suppose we have a DAG in the figure.[image]

I want to find the formula for $P(Y \mid do(X), S)$. What I think is that: Since $W$ is the parent of $X$ then we should have
$$
    P(Y \mid do(X), S) = \sum_{W} P(Y \mid do(X), W, S) P(W \mid S).
$$
I think this is something like backdoor criteria (although I cannot find a formula for solve this thing...)

Is this correct? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At a glance; having "already" intervened on $X$, there is no way for $S$ and $W$ to impact the outcome, so $P(Y \mid X)$ is sufficient to compute your estimand of interest. That is; your formula is correct but unnecessarily complicated, and can't be computed as-is due to the presence of the $do(\cdot)$ operators. But let's go more slowly through Pearl's do-calculus rules. Some notational preliminaries:

- We will call your DAG $G$.
- The DAG  $G_\overline{X}$ is the DAG resulting from removing incoming arrows in $G$ to node (or a set of nodes) $ X$, and likewise for $G_\underline{X}$.

Using two of the [three rules of do-calculus (Pearl, 2012)](https://ftp.cs.ucla.edu/pub/stat_ser/r402.pdf):

1. *[via rule 1: insertion/deletion of observations]* We can write $P(Y \mid do(X), S) = P(Y \mid do(X))$. This is because $Y \perp\!\!\!\perp S \mid X$ in $G_\overline{X}$, which holds by inspection ($Y, S$ aren't even in connected components of $G_\overline{X}$).
2. *[via rule 2: action/observation exchange]* We can write $P(Y \mid do(X)) = P(Y \mid X)$. This is because $Y \perp\!\!\!\perp X$ in $G_{\underline{X}}$. Verify that this is the case.

There you have it: $P(Y \mid do(X) , S) = P(Y \mid X)$ given your DAG $G$. You can then set $X$ to whatever realized value is entailed by the $do(\cdot)$ operator and proceed.

Comment: Thank you very much for your comprehensive explanation! Now, I understand what actually happens in this DAG!