# Do operator in a given DAG

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, causality, dag, causal-diagram

[The Original question is here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/627669/275277) Suppose we have a DAG in the figure.[image]

The question to is find the decomposition for $P(Y \mid do(X), S)$. If the backdoor criteria can be applied here, then the following one does hold
$$
    P(Y \mid do(X), S) = \sum_{W} P(Y \mid do(X), W, S) P(W \mid S).
$$
However, it seems that we can also apply frontdoor criteria and hen
$$
    P(Y \mid do(X), S) = P(Y \mid X, S) \sum_{W} P(Y \mid do(X), W, S) P(W \mid S).
$$

I wonder which is the correct one? Thanks in advance!

Comment: The first equation is correct, but at a glance, $P(Y \mid X, S) \neq 1$ in general, making the second false. What definition of front-door criterion are you using, and how are you applying it here? I usually see the front-door criterion in the context of dealing with a latent confounder when we have access to a mediator between the cause and effect variables (+ other requirements).

Comment: @chang_trenton Hi. I saw your answer, I thought I was wrong: we cannot use front door criterion as there is no other node between $X$ and $Y$. Thanks for your comments!