# A question about "do" operator under unobservable confounder

Tags: probability, conditional-probability, causality, dag, causal-diagram

[The original question is here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/627669/275277).  Suppose we have a DAG in the figure.[image]

If there is no confounder $U$, as chang_trenton point out since $S$ and $W$ happen before $X$, we have
$$
    P(Y \mid do(X), S) = P(Y \mid X) = \sum_{W} P(Y \mid do(X), W, S) P(W \mid S).
$$
However, I wonder what would happen if we consider the confounder $U$. As $W$ is not affected by $U$, I think $P(Y \mid do(X), S)$ is still identifiable, and can written as something like
$$
    P(Y \mid do(X), S) = P(Y \mid X) = \sum_{W} P(Y \mid do(X), W, S) P^*(W \mid S),
$$
where $P^*(W \mid S)$ is like a adjustment correction instead of the conditional probability $P(W \mid S)$. But I stuck here and do not know how to find $P^*(W \mid S)$.

Could anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is $g$? Why is $g(S)$ guaranteed to be in the support of $X$? Also, your first relation holds for any realization of $X$ (i.e., setting it to a particular value), so you'd simply be working with $P(Y \mid X = g(S))$; i.e., a conditional distribution of $Y$ given some value of $X$, instead of $P(Y \mid X)$ for some arbitrary $X$ (as in your previous question). As-is, I don't quite understand the distinction between your previous question and this one.

Comment: @chang_trenton Thank you for reply. The function $g$ is a specified function of $S$ whose range lies within the support of $X$. My main intrigue is to delve into the relationship and mechanisms by which $W$ and $S$ influence $X$ differently in $P(Y \mid do(X = g(S)), S)$. In my prior question, the intervention $do(X = x)$ is fixed at $x$, and thus, discerning the relationship between $S$ and $W$ might not have seemed necessary, while we're setting $X$ based on $S$ through the function $g$ without $W$ now.

Comment: @chang_trenton Hi, I understand your point now. I looked into my original question, and found I should formulate my question as above. I have updated it now. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: If you condition on $S,$ I think you could use $W$ as an instrument, here.

Comment: @AdrianKeister Thanks! I agree with your comment. But I still wonder how to write down the conditional probability.